# Converting Base64 string to file and saving locally using vbscript

Tags: vbscript, adodb

I'm getting the error mentioned below when i try to decode a base64 string to file and save it locally. I've done some research online and couldn't find the solution. Thanks in advance.

**Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another.**

```
    Const adTypeBinary = 1
    Dim str 
    str = strBase64Content 'base64 string here

    Dim objXML 
    Dim objNode

    Set objXML = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
    Set objNode = objXML.createElement("b64")
    objNode.DataType = "bin.base64"
    objNode.Text = strBase64Content
    decodeBase64 = objNode.nodeTypedValue

    Set objNode = Nothing
    Set objXML = Nothing

    set stream =  server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    stream.Open
    stream.Type = adTypeBinary
    stream.Write decodeBase64
    stream.SaveToFile "C:\"
    stream.Close
```